# How to navigate back to first specific screen with navigation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Suppose the navigation screen stack as below:

A -> B -> C -> A

A is the current screen, and I need to navigate to the first A with parameters. I have try `navigation.popToTop()`, but it can't carry parameter.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What version of `react-navigation` are you using?

Comment: Generally speaking, instead of PUSH actions from A -> B and B -> C, you could use REPLACE actions so when on C you can issue a final REPLACE back to A, along with any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I config different names A1 and A2 for the two screen A which is the same component. It is not feasible that to use `replace` instead of `push` as @Drew Reese commented, because there is a back button on A2 and need to navigate back to C when pressed.

A1 -> B -> C -> A2.

```
<MainStack.Screen name='A1' component={A} />
<MainStack.Screen name='B' component={B} />
<MainStack.Screen name='C' component={C} />
<MainStack.Screen name='A2' component={A} />
```

Then I can push to A2, and navigate back to A1 as requirement, B & C & A2 all pop-up.